# How can I get these elements to display on the same lines?

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm running into some issues here and was hoping maybe someone could point me in the right direction. I'm fairly new to CSS, so i'm sure that i'm maybe not calling or possibly not properly defining something here. Anyways, to my questions that I hope you can help with.

1. My symbol ( AwesomeFonts ) isn't falling inline with the text, instead it's jumping below it. I tried setting it to inline-block but it seems to behave like a block element!!!
2. My h1 tags are causing my

   elements to completely fall out of my posts divs!!

Bonus: CSS books, tutorials, anything to help me get better is the aim!

My code is featured below:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Cultcakes</title>
        <link href="hover.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Space+Mono"             rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3d519e8670.js"></script>


        </head>

        <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <nav>
        <section>
        <img src="Images/Chalk_instagram.png"><img src="Images/Chalk_pinterest.png"><img src="Images/Chalk_twitter.png">
        </section>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home <i class="fa fa-arrow-left hvr-icon-pulse-grow  " aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Destinations</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
       </nav>
       <section id="details">
       <div id="posts">
       <p>
       <h1>TITLE</h1>
        Aliquam tempus odio non bibendum cursus. Donec eget est eu elit mattis iaculis. Phasellus et odio placerat, porta dui vitae, dictum urna. Maecenas vestibulum consequat varius. Nam quam arcu, molestie eu vestibulum et, tempor non urna. Sed fringilla nec turpis eu pellentesque. Vivamus mi velit, porta non tortor id, bibendum molestie tortor. Suspendisse arcu augue, malesuada in odio id, dignissim sagittis ligula. Duis quis enim vitae velit lobortis egestas ac id mauris. Sed dictum pharetra quam, et egestas est placerat sit amet. Aenean at lacus ut magna sagittis tincidunt. Vivamus pulvinar nunc enim, ut bibendum massa semper non. Nunc euismod ex nec nisl viverra feugiat. Nulla facilisi. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
      </p>

      <p>
        Nunc ut malesuada diam. Fusce risus leo, ullamcorper sed lobortis ut, malesuada et nulla. Morbi lacinia quam erat, eget cursus mi accumsan at. In nec congue dolor. Nulla tortor libero, condimentum ut justo feugiat, commodo ultrices erat. Praesent quis tempus ligula. Curabitur fringilla diam nisi, nec cursus sem mattis ut. Donec at auctor tellus.
    </p>
    <p>
    <h1> TITLE</h1>
        Donec mattis bibendum justo accumsan semper. In gravida tincidunt libero. Nunc ac eros sed libero feugiat tempus at in tellus. Pellentesque dui diam, pretium egestas tincidunt quis, vehicula vitae sapien. Nulla at massa tempus, lacinia est ac, varius lacus. Fusce porta, tortor vel interdum congue, sapien nunc tempor massa, et congue elit nulla at dolor. Fusce luctus auctor diam, nec pellentesque augue. Mauris at sapien tincidunt, pharetra odio sit amet, pellentesque metus.

    </p>

    <p>
        Donec mattis bibendum justo accumsan semper. In gravida tincidunt libero. Nunc ac eros sed libero feugiat tempus at in tellus. Pellentesque dui diam, pretium egestas tincidunt quis, vehicula vitae sapien. Nulla at massa tempus, lacinia est ac, varius lacus. Fusce porta, tortor vel interdum congue, sapien nunc tempor massa, et congue elit nulla at dolor. Fusce luctus auctor diam, nec pellentesque augue. Mauris at sapien tincidunt, pharetra odio sit amet, pellentesque metus.

    </p>
    </div>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
</html>
```

My mainstyle.CSS Code is here:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #F8C0C8;
    color: #DC143C;
    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
    background-image:  url("http://s3.amazonaws.com/spoonflower/public/design_thumbnails/0465/6155/rrhearts_bg_pink_shop_preview.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #FCA6AB;
    border-right: 3px solid white;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100px;

}
h1 {
    background-color: pink;
    font-size: 10px;
}
li {

    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
    margin-top: 105px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
a {
    display: inline-block;
}
li a{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;

}
li a:hover{
    background-color: #F8C0C8;
    color: #E7656D;
}

div#wrapper {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
/* Background Image */
article#img {
    height: 1024px;
    width: 900px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url("cakechick.jpg")  ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 275px;

    }

/*----overlay----*/
article.overlay{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /*dim the background*/
}
section {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 80%;


}
section img {
    padding: 2px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;

}
section#details {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 270px;



}
section#details p {
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}
div#post {
    position: inherit;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

Any my hover.css i've been trying to experiment with :D

```
/* Icon Pulse Grow */
@-webkit-keyframes hvr-icon-pulse-grow {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
}
@keyframes hvr-icon-pulse-grow {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
}
.hvr-icon-pulse-grow {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 40px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;


}
.hvr-icon-pulse-grow:before {
  content: "\f060";
  position: absolute;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-icon-pulse-grow:hover:before, .hvr-icon-pulse-grow:focus:before, .hvr-icon-pulse-grow:active:before {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-icon-pulse-grow;
  animation-name: hvr-icon-pulse-grow;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Comment: The arrow is by "home" for me? Re: the `h1`, it can't be a child of `p`. Just move it outside/above the `p`

Comment: Are you using codepen ? When I do that, it displays beside each other but when I open the main file from my cpu through sublimetext3 it won't display properly.  So I moved the h1 from the p element, but I want it to display inside the white box with the border. Should I make separate divs for this?

Comment: yeah codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryvmJV and yep, just add a new element to wrap the `h1` and `p` and apply the background/border to that new element.

Comment: Yea, having a fiddle or something would be super nice and likely garner more answers.

Comment: @MichaelCoker thanks! I just applied that, worked awesome. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Pytth fiddle? Is that a website or program? Fairly new to stackoverflow, I use to just depend on reddit ^^

Comment: @EssenceSmith Oh! Welcome! Yea, jsfiddle.net is a great site that lets you test out bits of HTML/JS/CSS and makes it super simple to show people what you mean. Give it a shot!

Comment: awesome! np :) and by "fiddle" @Pytth means jsfiddle, aka http://jsfiddle.net - it's an alternative to codepen.

Comment: Thanks so much guys! First time asking a question here, and I didn't realize the community was so awesome :)

Comment: @EssenceSmith Lastly, please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) in the Help Center

Comment: @ChrisHappy thanks!! I was wondering how I closed questions and stuff :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to improve code:

- Add `min-width: 200px;` to `nav`. This makes the the ul not be able to collapse small enough to "bump" the icon below the list item.
- Bring `h1` out of paragraphs and wrap the `p` and the `h1` tag with `.post`
- Change `h1` to `h3`. There should only be one `h1` tag per page, such as the title of the page, and `h2` is normally a subtitle, the slogan. The `h3` is a good fit the title of the posts.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/xev7v4j0/1)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #F8C0C8;
  color: #DC143C;
  font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
  background-image: url("http://s3.amazonaws.com/spoonflower/public/design_thumbnails/0465/6155/rrhearts_bg_pink_shop_preview.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  min-width: 200px;
  /* This code */
  background-color: #FCA6AB;
  border-right: 3px solid white;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

h3 {
  background-color: pink;
  font-size: 10px;
}

li {
  font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
  margin-top: 105px;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #F8C0C8;
  color: #E7656D;
}

div#wrapper {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}


/* Background Image */

article#img {
  height: 1024px;
  width: 900px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("cakechick.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: 275px;
}


/*----overlay----*/

article.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /*dim the background*/
}

section {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 80%;
}

section img {
  padding: 2px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

section#details {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 270px;
}

section#details .post {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

div#post {
  /* #posts? */
  position: inherit;
  padding: 50px;
}


/* Icon Pulse Grow */

@-webkit-keyframes hvr-icon-pulse-grow {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-icon-pulse-grow {
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
}

.hvr-icon-pulse-grow {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 40px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
}

.hvr-icon-pulse-grow:before {
  content: "\f060";
  position: absolute;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}

.hvr-icon-pulse-grow:hover:before,
.hvr-icon-pulse-grow:focus:before,
.hvr-icon-pulse-grow:active:before {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-icon-pulse-grow;
  animation-name: hvr-icon-pulse-grow;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3d519e8670.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <section>
      <img src="Images/Chalk_instagram.png"><img src="Images/Chalk_pinterest.png"><img src="Images/Chalk_twitter.png">
    </section>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span><i class="fa fa-arrow-left hvr-icon-pulse-grow  " aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Destinations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="details">
    <div id="posts">
      <div class="post">
        <h3>TITLE</h3>
        <p>
          Aliquam tempus odio non bibendum cursus. Donec eget est eu elit mattis iaculis. Phasellus et odio placerat, porta dui vitae, dictum urna. Maecenas vestibulum consequat varius. Nam quam arcu, molestie eu vestibulum et, tempor non urna. Sed fringilla nec
          turpis eu pellentesque. Vivamus mi velit, porta non tortor id, bibendum molestie tortor. Suspendisse arcu augue, malesuada in odio id, dignissim sagittis ligula. Duis quis enim vitae velit lobortis egestas ac id mauris. Sed dictum pharetra quam,
          et egestas est placerat sit amet. Aenean at lacus ut magna sagittis tincidunt. Vivamus pulvinar nunc enim, ut bibendum massa semper non. Nunc euismod ex nec nisl viverra feugiat. Nulla facilisi. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
          montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
        </p>
      </div>


      <div class="post">
        <p>
          Nunc ut malesuada diam. Fusce risus leo, ullamcorper sed lobortis ut, malesuada et nulla. Morbi lacinia quam erat, eget cursus mi accumsan at. In nec congue dolor. Nulla tortor libero, condimentum ut justo feugiat, commodo ultrices erat. Praesent quis
          tempus ligula. Curabitur fringilla diam nisi, nec cursus sem mattis ut. Donec at auctor tellus.
        </p>

      </div>

      <div class="post">
        <h3> TITLE</h3>
        <p> Donec mattis bibendum justo accumsan semper. In gravida tincidunt libero. Nunc ac eros sed libero feugiat tempus at in tellus. Pellentesque dui diam, pretium egestas tincidunt quis, vehicula vitae sapien. Nulla at massa tempus, lacinia est ac,
          varius lacus. Fusce porta, tortor vel interdum congue, sapien nunc tempor massa, et congue elit nulla at dolor. Fusce luctus auctor diam, nec pellentesque augue. Mauris at sapien tincidunt, pharetra odio sit amet, pellentesque metus.

        </p>

      </div>
      <div class="post">
        <p>
          Donec mattis bibendum justo accumsan semper. In gravida tincidunt libero. Nunc ac eros sed libero feugiat tempus at in tellus. Pellentesque dui diam, pretium egestas tincidunt quis, vehicula vitae sapien. Nulla at massa tempus, lacinia est ac, varius
          lacus. Fusce porta, tortor vel interdum congue, sapien nunc tempor massa, et congue elit nulla at dolor. Fusce luctus auctor diam, nec pellentesque augue. Mauris at sapien tincidunt, pharetra odio sit amet, pellentesque metus.

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Note: click " Run code snippet" then "Expand snippet" to view full page.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/xev7v4j0/1)

Comment: Just did that, and thanks for that tip about proper usage of h1/h3 tags! :)

Comment: Thank you for the tip with the width for the ul! I know my answered my questions but I noticed you used a <span> on Home,  will this only work if I set the symbol ( img etc ) to inline-block ? I know span is used to group those sort of elements, just curious on your call for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the questions:

1. I think I am missing something, can you clarify and give more info?
2. Probably because you have a typo in your mainstyle.CSS: the `div#post` should be `div#posts` to match your HTML `<div id="posts">`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I made the adjustments :) The arrow ( symbol ) I just want to display beside the text. It seems to work in codepen just fine but notsomuch when I use it direct from sublime text.